# Android start activity by FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK,when back the other activity fullscreen is invalid

Tags: android, kotlin

**1.** start activity `A`，set fullscreen in `Activity.onCreate` callback**

**2.** start service `Service`

**3.** Start activity `B`(FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK) in service，set fullscreen in `Activity.onCreate` callback

But,when back `B`，the `A` fullscreen is invaild,again set fullscreen in `A.onResume` callback,`A` fullsceen will recover normal

**set fullscreen method:**

```kotlin
 val lp = window.attributes
        lp.layoutInDisplayCutoutMode =
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.LAYOUT_IN_DISPLAY_CUTOUT_MODE_SHORT_EDGES
        window.attributes = lp
        val decorView = window.decorView
        val uiOptions =
            View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION or View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION or View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY
        decorView.systemUiVisibility = uiOptions
```

Is there any other solution？

Answer (score 0):

Try this code to hide status bar

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.R) {
     getWindow().getInsetsController().hide(WindowInsets.Type.statusBars());
} else {
     this.getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
}
```